# Having trouble running android sdk tool on 12.10

Tags: command-line, java, android

When I try to run the Android SDK Manager from the command line it doesn't open.
Keeps giving me command not found or permission denied message like so.

```
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ pwd
/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
bash: /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: Permission denied
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$ sudo /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android
sudo: /media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools/android: command not found
osama@prometheus:/media/osama/develop/android-sdk-linux/tools$
```

Am I missing something? Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you could not run it is because the SDK was on an external drive mounted with the `noexec` flag active. If you run the `mount` command you should see the word `noexec` on the line of the external drive. This is a safety feature to prevent executing malicious software by accident. As a result the `android` binary could not have the executable bit set, hence you could not run it.

Copying it to a different disk (as you did) where you can set the executable bit with `chmod +x /path/to/android` is the solution.